# Sign in with Apple button Apple logo is appearing small

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, apple-sign-in

Apple logo appears small. I gave the 44px height to the appleSignView in xib.

The code that I am using:

```swift
private func setupAppleSignIn() {
   let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(authorizationButtonType: .signIn, authorizationButtonStyle: .white)
   rootView.appleSignView.isHidden = false
   button.frame = rootView.appleSignView.bounds
   print(button.frame)
   rootView.appleSignView.addSubview(button)
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Is this the default behaviour of that button or am I doing something wrong?
[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukbve.png)

Comment: Please check your localisation.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue and Apple has rejected my app because of it, they seem to not like their own button which is sad.

I ended up downloading the Icon pack from:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/

And created my own icon like the following:

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *))
    {
        self.appleIDButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,
                                                                       y,
                                                                       44,
                                                                       44)];
        UIImage *appleButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appleLogin.png"];
        [self.appleIDButton setImage:appleButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.appleIDButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleAuthrization:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.appleIDButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.appleIDButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
        self.appleIDButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        self.appleIDButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
```

Comment: With the above, it not showing the apple button

Answer (score 0):

```
 func setupSignInButton() {
    
    let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignInWithAppleTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.cornerRadius = 10
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -350).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).